# Qual a finalidade do "continue" em C?

Tags: c, c++, loop

```
  int main ()
    {
       /* local variable definition */
       int a = 10;

       /* do loop execution */
       do
       {
          if( a == 15)
          {
             /* skip the iteration */
             a = a + 1;
             continue;
          }
          printf("value of a: %d\n", a);
          a++;

       }while( a < 20 );

       return 0;
    }
```

O que faz a função `continue`?

Comment: a execução do código é exactamente igual com 'continue' ou sem ele, qual é vantagem de ter o continue no código?

Comment: Explique melhor esta afirmação, porque não é o que parece.

Comment: eu executei o código com o comando 'continue' e logo a  seguir experimentei sem ele, e o resultado era exactamente o mesmo, o que parece não haver diferença em haver ou não o comando

Comment: Você só tirou o `continue`e mais nada? O exemplo é muito ruim para indicar a funcionalidade dele. Por sinal o TutorialsPoint de onde você pegou isto é bem ruim. Vou colocar exemplos melhores.

Comment: sim só tirei o continue, se pudesse colocar outro exemplo era bom. obrigado.

Comment: Veja a minha resposta.

Comment: eu já vi a sua resposta senhor ramaral, o seu output é exactamente o que  obti, com o comando 'continue' ou sem ele

Comment: Não pode ser. Posso estar a ver mal mas se tiver o `continue` o número 15 não é apresentado.

Comment: é verdade ! mas sem o continue o número 15 continua a não ser representado

Comment: Fui testar e verifico que você tem razão. Isso se deve a que `a` é incrementado dentro do bloco do `if == 15`

Comment: eu já fiquei esclarecido da dúvida, obrigado senhor ramaral

Comment: Aqui um [exemplo simples](https://ideone.com/u8oeZ6) em php para vc entender o continue. Ele está pulando etapas neste caso.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

O `continue` é um comando da linguagem e não uma função. Esta distinção é importante.

Quando o código chegar no `continue` ele será desviado para o **final** do laço que ele está no momento. Do laço mais interno se houver laços aninhados. Todas as linhas entre o `continue` e o final do laço serão ignoradas. Por isto não faz sentido usar um `continue` fora de uma estrutura condicional, já que isto faria as linhas a seguir dele sempre serem ignoradas.

No final, dependendo do laço ele poderá verificar uma condição existente, como é o caso do seu exemplo, e decidir se deve ou não continuar executando o laço. Se continuar, obviamente ele pulará para o início do laço, o `do`.

Se for um `while` simples no início do laço ou um `for`, ele irá para o final, como não existe nada a fazer lá, ele desviará para o início e lá operará a condição do `while` ou executará o passo do `for` e a condição de saída dele. Se a condição indicar que o laço deve ser encerrado, ele desviará para o final novamente.

Entenda por final uma marca logo antes do primeiro comando depois do bloco do laço. Então quando encerrar o bloco, no seu exemplo, ele vai para o `return 0;`

Veja seu exemplo modificado para demonstrar melhor o efeito do `continue`. Ele realmente não faz diferença em certos fluxos.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/C2syc7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhithoutContinuec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/WithContinue.c) **com** `continue`.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Al4HHJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/WhithoutContinuec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/WithoutContinue.c) **sem** `continue`.

Algumas pessoas costumam dizer que um `for` assim:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        x++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

**seria** igual ao `while` a:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10) {
    printf("%d\n", x);
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        x++;
        continue;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Sem considerar o escopo de `x` que é mais local no primeiro caso, isto não vem ao caso neste exemplo, eles parecem fazer o mesmo. Declara e inicializa a variável, repete até que a variável chegue em 10 e no final de cada passo do laço a variável é incrementada em 1. Em cada passo verifica se o valor é par, se for ele incrementa um e pula para o fim do laço ignorando o que vem a seguir.

Percebe como a execução será diferente por causa do `continue`? No `for` a execução do fim do passo é obrigatória, no caso do `while` a execução do mesmo passo pode ser condicionada.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/dNOvZ8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Forc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/For.c) com `for`.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/YwH0Dy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Whilec). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/While.c) com `while`.

Comment: percebi bem a função do continue com os seus exemplos, obrigado

Comment: O que é um laço?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel é um *loop*, um bloco de repetição.

Comment: Ah, um ciclo... Porquê que não se chama ciclo?

Comment: Porque eu sou brasileiro :P

Answer (score 16):

`continue` é um dos comandos que podem ser utilizados para modificar o percurso normal da execução de loops.

O comando `continue` passa o controle para a próxima iteração do *loop*, ignorando as restantes instruções. A próxima iteração começa pela reavaliação da expressão do *loop*, sendo a iteração executada ou não em função dessa avaliação.

Um outro comando é o `break` que faz com que o loop seja terminado de imediato, continuando a execução a partir da instrução a seguir à chaveta que fecha o código do loop.
O código entre o break e a chaveta é ignorado.

No caso do seu código, ao ser encontrado o `continue`, a avaliação da condição é verdadeira e a execução salta para a linha `if( a == 15)`

O intuito do código é fazer com que o numero 15 não seja mostrado na tela.

O output será:

```
value of a: 10
value of a: 11
value of a: 12
value of a: 13
value of a: 14
value of a: 16
value of a: 17
value of a: 18
value of a: 19
```

Answer (score 14):

Geralmente, em qualquer linguagem, o `continue` indica que a iteração atual do laço de repetição deverá "pular" para a próxima iteração.

Considere um exemplo para impressão de apenas números pares

Exemplo em PHP:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 != 0) continue;
    echo $i;
}
```

Imprime:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: Resposta simples e com um ótimo exemplo +1.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, está aqui uma péssima piada que você poderia fazer: _`continue` assim_

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sugiro dar um `break` nesse ciclo de piadas ruins.