# Por que o uso do "break" é considerado ruim?

Tags: loop, característica-linguagem, estilo-de-codificação, controle-de-fluxo

Em muitos lugares já ouvi diversos comentários sobre isso, como:

- "Programador profissional não usa break"
- "O código já não presta quando você vê um break"

Porque o uso do `break` é tão mal visto pela maioria dos desenvolvedores?

Pessoalmente não vejo o `break`como uma instrução ruim, em muitos casos eu o utilizo para deixar o programa um pouco mais rápido, como em um `for`:

```
for ($letter = 0; $letter < count($keyArray); $letter ++)
{
    if(filter_var($keyArray[$letter], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
        $contNumber ++;
    else
        break;
}
```

Tenho esse exemplo simples, no qual o objetivo é contar quantos números tem no inicio de uma `string`, por exemplo, tenho a `string` `"145StackOverflow"`, então `$contNumber` será igual a 3.

Nesses casos eu uso o `break`, pois quando o caractere atual não ser mais um inteiro eu não terei mais números na `string`, logo não precisarei ficar rodando o `for`.

Caso esqueceu a pergunta: Por que o uso do `break` é tão mal visto pela maioria dos desenvolvedores?

Comment: Desculpem se foi duplicata, pesquisei aqui no StackOverflow mas não achei pergunta igual.

Comment: Não é a mesma pergunta, mas acho que vale uma leitura aqui como comparação, o problema é bem parecido: [Por que devo usar apenas um “return” em cada função?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2477/). O problema está em quem faz a este tipo de afirmação, e não no break. Situação similar aqui: [Por que o uso de GOTO é considerado ruim?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20660/) - Fica a sugestão de, ao ouvir uma afirmação dessas dada com tanta certeza, colocar quem falou na lista de "fontes não confiáveis".

Comment: Eu acho que é gosto, eu prefiro não usar, prefiro colocar todas as condições de parada dentro do while/for, acho que fica mais fácil de dar manutenção e mais legível concentrando as condições em um mesmo lugar.

Comment: @lvcs vou responder. Tem uma citação para eu ser mais específico?

Comment: Não, sem citação, é mais em um contexto global mesmo. Estava contribuindo com um framework quando usei um break e lembrei dessas muitas pessoas que já me disseram isso kk

Comment: Tem até um seriado que critica o uso do break, se chama Breaking Bad *\*tudum tss\**

Comment: @Piovezan Fumou o que? Kkkk

Comment: Mas o Michael Jackson era favorável, "Ba dum tsss tsss tsss tsss" :)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128845/eval-%C3%A9-mocinho-ou-bandido

Comment: Relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88747/deve-se-usar-break-em-for

Comment: A condição "extra" que faz o fluxo de execução chegar no break; pode bem ficar dentro do "for".

Comment: Só que compromete a legibilidade do código e até o entendimento do mesmo.

Comment: Convém notar que na Conferência de Padrões (PLoP) de 1998 foram apresentados padrões de laços com amplo uso do `break`: https://users.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As pessoas têm preconceitos. Até com comandos de linguagens. No fundo o que dizem ser ruim mesmo é o uso do `goto`, cujo mito eu já dou uma detonada em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101). Dizem que o `break` é um `goto` disfarçado, principalmente se ele possuir um *label* e puder desviar para um ponto específico do código.

Há quem critique especificamente o `break` porque ele não deixa seguir o curso natural do algoritmo (aaah, vá?). Consideram que o correto é desenvolver uma lógica que o término seja decidido exclusivamente pela condição do laço. É dito que sempre é possível reescrever o código para não precisar do `break`. E é verdade, isso é o **ideal**. Usam até algum exemplo onde o código fica bom, às vezes até melhor sem o uso deste comando. Mas não costumam mostrar os casos que fica pior. Prejudicam a legibilidade ou até a simplicidade para atender uma regra sem sentido.

É claro que usar onde não precisa, onde fica pior, usar como solução "fácil", realmente é ruim, ninguém discute, até porque quem costuma fazer essas construções ruins (o leigo) não consegue e não está interessado em discutir sobre o assunto.

No exemplo do código da pergunta parece fazer sentido. A quebra ocorre por uma situação independente da condição que controla o término do laço. Também não seria um absurdo eliminá-lo, mas eu acho que fica menos legível. É opinião:

```
for ($letter = 0; $letter < count($keyArray) && filter_var($keyArray[$letter], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); $letter++) {
    $contNumber++;
}
```

Certamente fica menor, mas é mais difícil de ler e principalmente de compreender porque está fazendo essa condição. Não é normal usar um `for` assim. Nem imagino a complicação se tiver uma manutenção e a condição ficar mais complexa. Mas concordo que não é o fim do mundo fazer assim. Não vou brigar com quem goste :)

Talvez alguém pregue usar um `while` para ficar mais apropriado para uma condição mais complexa. Acho que fica pior, pelo menos nesse caso. Realmente em bons laços `while` o `break` tende ser menos útil, mas ainda existe lugar para ele.

Tem quem crie uma variável de *flag* para "facilitar". Parabéns! Ficará bem melhor `</sarcasmo>`.

Em geral ele é mais útil no início do laço. Quando vai pro meio, tende a ficar menos útil. Se estiver no final, tem boa chance de ter alguma coisa errada aí. Note que o exemplo citado é bom porque o `break` está no início, no meio e no fim :P

Na verdade muita gente teria usado um `foreach`:

```
foreach ($keyArray as $letter) {
    if (filter_var($letter, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
        $contNumber++;
    else
        break;
}
```

Resolva sem `break`!

Outra forma que alguns prefeririam:

```
foreach ($keyArray as $letter) {
    if (!filter_var($letter, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
        break;
    $contNumber++;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/Break.php).

Talvez, mais uma vez, venha de uma ideia do passado. Era comum ter grandes laços, era fácil fazer uma lógica esquisita, se perder ali no meio e uma quebra só agravava o problema. Mas hoje todo programador bom faz laços curtos. Os ruins vão fazer tudo errado mesmo, não será o `break` que causará as dores de cabeça no seu código. Claro, não pode abusar, tem que fazer certo.

Hoje é raro ver alguém criticando o `break`, só alguns "acadêmicos" que só aceitam uma solução como certa. Tem [estudo mostrando que é mais comum cometerem erros evitando esses controles facilitadores](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/papers/SIGCSE-1995/LoopExits.pdf).

Curiosamente uma das críticas é que ele é imprevisível. Aí você vai ver e a pessoa defende o uso de exceção, a rainha da imprevisibilidade :D

Criticam o [`continue`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80589/101) também, que eu acho um mito maior ainda. É óbvio que há casos que melhorar o `if` pode eliminar o `continue` ou o `break`, se for possível eliminar sem prejudicar o código, eu acho que deve fazer mesmo.

**Programador ruim é considerado ruim** :P ou melhor ainda "Harmful programmer is considered harmful".

Relacionado: [Deve-se usar break em for?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88747/101)

Comment: O que seria do `switch` sem um `break` :) hehe.

Comment: Pensei na mesma coisa, seria melhor fazer 10 if's do que um switch com break ?  Tornaria o código bem pior de ler

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro aí não é questão de ser pior de ler, é que faria outra coisa bem diferente. Por isso algumas linguagens optaram pelo `Switch` *fallthrough*.

Comment: Digo, fazer `if(a == "1"){}else if(a == "2"){}...` só pra não usar o break

Comment: @L Ah, entendi. Aí tem razão.

Comment: Pra complementar a discussão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88747/deve-se-usar-break-em-for