# Como sair de um ciclo no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

Preciso de sair do `foreach` quando o valor for igual a 1

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvValetes)
    if(dr.Cells["valor"].toString()=="1")
        //Sair aqui
```

Não sei como fazer...

Comment: Poste o seu código completo

Comment: Já coloquei o código do ciclo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para sair do ciclo use o comando `break`

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvValetes)
   if (dr.Cells["valor"].ToString()=="1")
      break;
```

Comment: "[...]It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent." Trecho retirado do MSDN sobre o método string.CompareTo(). MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Editado, obrigado

Answer (score 8):

Partindo do princípio que a condição está correta e faz o que deseja só precisa do [`break`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/101) para sair do laço ali:

```
foreach (var dr in dgvValetes) {
    if (dr.Cells["valor"].ToString() == "1") break;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Break.cs).

Note que preferi colocar as chaves para evitar problemas futuros de manutenção e criar alguma confusão.

<sup>Por razões históricas (havia um erro na outra resposta):</sup>

Mandar trocar a comparação de *string* usando o operador `==` pelo método `CompareTo()` não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Editado, obrigado

Comment: Exatamente o que eu ia dizer. Trocar `==` por `CompareTo()` não faz sentido nenhum.