# length() dando NullPointerException

Tags: java

Estou criando um programa que receberá múltiplos inputs do usuário e, ao receber uma string em branco, deverá parar de receber entradas e continuar em frente com o programa.

O código roda perfeitamente pelo meu computador porém o sistema de correção automatizado da faculdade relata um erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at SentencaDancante.main(SentencaDancante.java:20)
```

A linha 20 corresponde ao `while` do código abaixo:

```java
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String entrada = new String(input.readLine());

int contador = 0;

Frases[] objetos = new Frases[100];


while (entrada.length() != 0){

    //the object constructor gets the length and the char[], converted from the "entrada" string.

    objetos[contador] = new Frases(entrada.length(), entrada.toCharArray());

    // defined method in the Frases class
    objetos[contador].converter();

    entrada = input.readLine();

    contador++;

}
```

Já tentei substituir o `while` por um `while(entrada != null || entrada.length != 0)`. Mas aí o VSCode começa a relatar nullpointeraccess.

Comment: Posso dar uma olhada na sua classe Frases?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é a NullPointerException e quais são suas principais causas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63617/o-que-%c3%a9-a-nullpointerexception-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-causas)

Comment: Já tinha dado uma olhada nesse mesmo post, não atendia ao que eu precisava. Era um problema relacionado ao newline do sistema de correção automático

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O certo seria

`while(entrada != null && entrada.length() != 0)`

porque caso `entrada` for nulo não tentará executar a função `length` e não entrará no laço que também faz uso da `entrada`. Não é possivel executar uma função de um objeto nulo.

Comment: Tentarei implementar, é a melhor solução até agora. Não havia sacado que era necessário o AND e não o OR.  Muito obrigado

Comment: @DiogoNeiss o **AND** precisa que as duas condições sejam verdadeiras para entrar dentro do escopo, caso a primeira não seja ele não checará a segunda, ou seja, quando `entrada` for nulo ele não executará `entrada.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é mudar a forma como você lê os dados:

```
String entrada;
int contador = 0;
while ((entrada = input.readLine()) != null) { // enquanto conseguir ler alguma coisa
    if (entrada.length() == 0) // string vazia, sai do loop
        break;

    objetos[contador] = new Frases(entrada.length(), entrada.toCharArray());
    ... faz o que precisar com objetos[contador]

    contador++;
    if (contador == objetos.length) // já encheu o array, sai do loop
        break;
}
```

Dentro do while temos `(entrada = input.readLine()) != null` - repare nos parênteses: primeiro eu atribuo o retorno de `readLine` na variável `entrada`, e depois comparo se ele é `null`. Caso seja, já sai do loop.

Dentro do loop eu verifico se o tamanho da string é zero (e se for, sai do loop).

Também incluí uma verificação no final para saber se o contador já ultrapassou o tamanho do array (senão daria um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` quando o contador chegasse a 100).

---

No seu computador funcionava porque o `System.in` é lido do console e você sempre precisa dar um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, então a `entrada` nunca é nula (o `readLine` remove a quebra de linha referente ao <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, sobrando a string vazia).

Já no sistema de correção automatizado, provavelmente ele pega as entradas de algum arquivo e passa para o seu programa via *pipe* ou algo assim (não há um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> digitado), então [quando chega no final da *stream* de dados, o `readLine` retorna `null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--).

Comment: Devo admitir que eu não gosto de alterar o conteúdo de uma variável dentro da condição do laço, ainda mais com uma verificação logo em seguida com um `break`... mas desse jeito está melhor do que outras alternativas que vi/consigo pensar

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Concordo, eu também evito fazer isso, `BufferedReader` é um dos poucos casos em que faço...

Comment: Essa solução não funcionaria pra mim, esse meu professor é extremamente contrário ao uso de `breaks` no código. Vou tentar reformular essa questão da saída colocando um && dentro do while

Comment: @DiogoNeiss `break` [é uma solução perfeitamente válida](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18188123), então eu perguntaria pro professor porque ele é contra. Mas na minha opinião, ser contra **sem uma justificativa válida** é ridículo, o que vai dizer se deve usar ou não é o contexto do código...

Comment: @hkotsubo ele me disse uma vez que tinha a ver com o efeito do break na memória, com algo relacionado a pilhas ou algo assim. Além disso, um loop bem projetado é muito mais legível para manutenção que um repleto de `break`s e `continue`s. Há também a questão do salto dentro do programa, similar ao do `goto`.

Comment: @DiogoNeiss Indique para o seu professor alguns links: [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/131101/112052), [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20874/112052) e [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2478/112052). Resumindo, `break`, `continue` e `goto` são ferramentas, entenda como elas funcionam e aprenda qdo usar e qdo não usar. Há usos legítimos de `break` e se bem feito, é tão bom quanto um "loop bem projetado" (leia os links). Se o seu professor é contra "saltos" e preocupado com memória, então pergunte o que ele acha de exceções (se for coerente, ele deve dizer pra nunca usar também)