# Sair do laço For quando digitar a nota 1

Tags: java

Esse código que estou escrevendo, onde a **opção 1** o usuário digita notas que deseja inserir num caixa eletrônico onde **era pra parar quando a nota 1 fosse inserida**.

Na **opção 2** é pra inserir o valor do saque e esse saque só usará as notas que foram inseridas.

Na **opção 0** o programa se encerra.

Alguma maneira de eu conseguir injetar essa condição de **a nota 1 encerrar o laço**?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String menu = "* MENU OPÇÕES * " + "\n" + "1 - Notas Existentes" + "\n" + "2 - Saque" + "\n" + "0 - Sair" + "\n";
        int [] possiveis = new int [7];
        int work = 1;
        int div1=0,div2=0,div3 = 0,div4 = 0,div5 = 0,div6 = 0,div7 = 0;
        int resto1=0,resto2=0,resto3 = 0,resto4 = 0,resto5 = 0,resto6 = 0,resto7 = 0;
        while (work!=0) {
            System.out.println(menu);
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Digite a opçao desejada: ");
            int opcao = entrada.nextInt();
            if (opcao==1) {
                for (int i=0;i<possiveis.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println("Digite as notas disponiveis");
                    possiveis[i] = entrada.nextInt();
                }
                for (int i =0; i<possiveis.length;i++) {
                    if(possiveis[i]!=1) {
                        System.out.println(possiveis[i]);
                    }else if (possiveis[i]==1 ){
                        System.out.println(possiveis[i]);
                    }
                    work=1;
                }
            }else if (opcao==2) {
                System.out.println("Digite o valor do saque");
                int saque = entrada.nextInt();
                if ((possiveis[0]>0)|| (possiveis[1] >0) || (possiveis[2] >0) || (possiveis[3] >0) ||(possiveis[4]>0) || (possiveis[5]>0) || (possiveis[6]>0)){
                div1 = saque / possiveis[0];
                resto1 = saque % possiveis[0];
                if (resto1>0){

                div2 = resto1 / possiveis[1];
                resto2 = resto1 % possiveis[1];}
                if (resto2>0){
                div3 = resto2 / possiveis[2];
                resto3 = resto2 % possiveis[2];}
                if (resto3>0){
                div4 = resto3 / possiveis[3];
                resto4 = resto3 % possiveis[3];}
                if (resto4>0){
                div5 = resto4 / possiveis[4];
                resto5 = resto4 % possiveis[4];}
                if ( resto5>0){
                div6 = resto5 / possiveis [5];
                resto6 = resto5 % possiveis [5];}
                if (resto6>0){
                div7 = resto6 / possiveis [6];
                resto7 = resto6 % possiveis [6];}
                }

                if (div1!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[0] + " = " + div1);

                }
                if (div2!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[1] + " = " + div2);

                }
                if (div3!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[2] + " = " + div3);
                }
                if (div4!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[3] + " = " + div4);
                }
                if (div5!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[4] + " = " + div5);
                }
                if (div6!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total denotas de  " + possiveis[5] + " = " + div6);
                }
                if (div7!=0) {
                    System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[6] + " = " + div7);
                }
                work=1;
            }else if (opcao==0) {
                work=0;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Opcão invalida");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Usando um `break`?

Comment: Mas no caso era pra parar de digitar as notas depois de digitar 1,usando o break só vai resolver a questão da impressão de notas

Comment: Vc quer interromper o primeiro `for` (o que tem `possiveis[i] = entrada.nextInt()`)? Se for isso, pode colocar o `break` dentro do `for`, que somente o `for` é interrompido e o `while` continua rodando. Outra coisa, no segundo `for` vc faz: se o valor é diferente de 1, imprime, e se for igual a 1, também imprime, qual é o objetivo disso?

Comment: Realmente esse segundo for foi erro lógico meu haha,obrigado pelo toque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelos diversos comentários, dá a entender que você quer interromper este laço, quando for digitado `1`:

```
for (int i=0;i<possiveis.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite as notas disponiveis");
    possiveis[i] = entrada.nextInt();
}
```

Pois bem, basta usar o `break`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possiveis.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Digite as notas disponiveis");
    int valor = entrada.nextInt();
    if (valor == 1) {
        break;
    }
    possiveis[i] = valor;
}
```

Esse `break` só interrompe o `for`, e o `while` continua rodando normalmente (já que era essa a sua preocupação, segundo [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/415166/sair-do-la%c3%a7o-for-quando-digitar-a-nota-1#comment809094_415176)).

O problema é que, ao interromper o `for`, os elementos não inicializados terão o valor zero. E dependendo das notas e do valor do saque, você pode acabar dividindo por zero, o que causa um `ArithmeticException`.

---

Bom, vou aproveitar para sugerir algumas alterações no seu código.

Você está criando um `Scanner` dentro do `while`, o que quer dizer que a cada iteração é criado uma nova instância. Mas não precisa disso, pode criar apenas um no início (antes do `while`) e usá-lo em todo o programa.

O seu segundo `for` está bem estranho:

```
for (int i = 0; i < possiveis.length; i++) {
    if (possiveis[i] != 1) {
        System.out.println(possiveis[i]);
    } else if (possiveis[i] == 1) {
        System.out.println(possiveis[i]);
    }
    work = 1;
}
```

Se o valor for diferente de 1, imprime, e se for igual a 1, também imprime. Não sei o que você tentou fazer aqui, se foi algum erro de digitação ou outra coisa, mas do jeito que está não faz sentido. A atribuição de `work = 1` também é feita várias vezes, o que é redundante. Pelo que vi, essa linha pode ficar fora do `for`, logo depois dele.

Outro ponto é que você não precisa da variável `work`, basta fazer `while (true)` (um *loop* infinito) e interrompê-lo com `break` quando a opção for zero:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println(menu);
    System.out.println("Digite a opçao desejada: ");
    int opcao = entrada.nextInt();
    if (opcao == 1) {
        ...
    } else if (opcao == 2) {
        ...
    } else if (opcao == 0) {
        break; // <---- AQUI
    } else {
        System.out.println("Opcão invalida");
    }
}
```

Esse `break` acima interrompe o `while`, e ele não se confunde com o `break` que colocamos dentro do primeiro `for`. [Tem quem critique o uso de `break`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131093/112052), mas sinceramente, criar essa variável `work` eu acho pior.

Sugiro também quebrar cada funcionalidade em um método próprio. Por exemplo:

```
public void lerNotas(Scanner entrada, int[] possiveis) {
    for (int i = 0; i < possiveis.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite as notas disponiveis");
        int valor = entrada.nextInt();
        if (valor == 1) {
            break;
        }
        possiveis[i] = valor;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < possiveis.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(possiveis[i]);
    }
}

public void saque(Scanner entrada, int[] possiveis) {
    System.out.println("Digite o valor do saque");
    int saque = entrada.nextInt();
    int divs[] = new int[possiveis.length];
    int resto = saque;
    for (int i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (possiveis[i] != 0) {
            divs[i] = resto / possiveis[i];
            resto = resto % possiveis[i];
            if (resto == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i] != 0) {
            System.out.println("Total de notas de  " + possiveis[i] + " = " + divs[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que mudei o seu algoritmo de saque para usar *loops*. **Não conferi se ele funciona para todos os casos possíveis**, só peguei a sua lógica e transformei em um *loop*. De qualquer forma, se pesquisar no site, provavelmente encontrará vários algoritmos para este problema (vale lembrar que o seu algoritmo considera que existe uma quantidade ilimitada de notas - se quer considerar a quantidade de cada nota, aí é outro algoritmo e já foge do escopo da pergunta).

E no segundo `for`, retirei o `if`/`else` que não fazia sentido. Agora é só mudar o `while` para usar os métodos acima:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
String menu = "* MENU OPÇÕES * " + "\n" + "1 - Notas Existentes" + "\n" + "2 - Saque" + "\n" + "0 - Sair" + "\n";
int[] possiveis = new int[7];
while (true) {
    System.out.println(menu);
    System.out.println("Digite a opçao desejada: ");
    int opcao = entrada.nextInt();
    if (opcao == 1) {
        lerNotas(entrada, possiveis);
    } else if (opcao == 2) {
        saque(entrada, possiveis);
    } else if (opcao == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Opcão invalida");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para forçar a saída de um while basta usar a palavra reservada **break**. Exemplo:

```
while(condicao){
  if (opcao == 1) {
  // seu codigo aqui
  break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mas no caso eu n posso sair do while,ele tá sendo usado como menu do meu programa,eu queria era parar de digitar dentro do for quando inserir a nota 1