# Código para antes do esperado

Tags: c++, c++11

Segue o código com minhas suspeitas:

Header:

```
    class Name_pairs
{
public:
    void read_names();
    void read_ages(); 
    void print() const; 
    void sort(); // Ordenar os nomes com as idades        

private:
    std::vector<std::string>name;
    std::vector<double>age;    
};

#endif
```

Implementação:

```
void Name_pairs::read_names()
{
    cout << "Entre com os nomes desejados, digite 'SemNome' para finalizar a lista." << endl;
    string NomesVetor; 

    while (cin >> NomesVetor && NomesVetor != "SemNome")
    {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x) // confere se há nomes duplicados 
        {
            if (name[x] == NomesVetor) cout << "Nome repetido." << endl;
            name.push_back(NomesVetor);
        }
    }
}

void Name_pairs::read_ages()
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x)
    {
        cout << "Nome de " << name[x] << ": " << endl;
        double IdadesVetor;
        cin >> IdadesVetor;
        age.push_back(IdadesVetor);
    }
}

void Name_pairs::print() const                                                                                                                      
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x)
    {
        cout << "Nome: " << name[x] << ", Idade: " << age[x] << endl;
    }
} 

void Name_pairs::sort() 
{
    vector<string> strCopia = name;
    vector<double> dbCopia = age; 

    std::sort(begin(name), end(name)); 

    for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < name.size(); ++y)
        {
            if (name[x] == strCopia[y]) age[x] = dbCopia[y];

        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Name_pairs objeto;
    objeto.read_names();
    objeto.read_ages();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

O erro é quando eu insiro os nomes e finalizo a entrada digitando 'SemNome', o programa simplesmente fecha. Temo que o erro esteja na função `Read_names()` que pode não estar dando continuidade para a `read_ages()` ou no próprio `Main.cpp`, já que estou iniciando agora as classes e não entendo muito bem ainda das chamadas.

Comment: Não ficou claro qual é o erro.

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe. O erro é que o programa finaliza após inserir os nomes e dar o SemNome. Ele simplesmente finaliza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
name.push_back(NomesVetor);
```

Ela está no lugar errado e não está adicionando nada já que ele só adiciona se for um nome repetido, que não é o que deseja e nem deve estar testando isto. Assim:

```
while (cin >> NomesVetor && NomesVetor != "SemNome") {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < name.size(); ++x) { // confere se há nomes duplicados 
         if (name[x] == NomesVetor) cout << "Nome repetido." << endl;
    }
    name.push_back(NomesVetor);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4kA9Y4). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/acsyzllc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/PushBack.cpp).

Note que ele está informando que está repetindo e não está impedindo isto. Talvez falte um [`continue`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80589/101) aí.

O código como um todo não é bem do jeito que se costuma fazer isto, mas este é outro problema.

Comment: Eu tava pra responder, mas vc foi mais rápido. Toma meu +1. :)

Comment: Estou testando alguns métodos e pesquisando outros mais práticos, o for dentro do for é substituível e irei faze-lo depois. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.