# Para que serve o controle de fluxo continue?

Tags: c#

Encontrei esse código explicando o controle de fluxo `continue`.

```
    string []  nomes = new string[] { "Macoratti", "Miriam", "Pedro"};
    foreach (string nome in nomes)
    {
        if (nome == "Miriam")
            continue;
        Console.WriteLine (nome);
    }
```

> O comando continue também é usado em laços(`while, for, etc.`) quando em
>   execução o comando continue irá mover a execução para o próxima
>   iteração no laço sem executar as linhas de código depois de continue.

**Saída:**

> Macoratti
>
> Pedro

- Como funciona o `continue`?
- Em que situações o seu uso é útil?
- Porque a saída não imprime o nome **Miriam**?

Comment: Acho que é dup mesmo sendo outra linguagem, porque é idêntico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80589/101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serve justamente pra controlar o fluxo do laço. Ele faz com que a execução vá pro próximo laço, só isso.

> Em que situações o seu uso é útil?

Quando você pretende ignorar o resto do código no laço e partir para o próximo.

> Porque a saída não imprimi o nome Miriam?

Justamente porque quando `nome` for igual a `Miriam` o código manda ir pro próximo laço, ignorando tudo o que vem depois.

---

Um exemplo em JS, pra ficar claro.

```js
var numero = 0;
while(numero < 10)
{
    numero++;
    console.log("-"); // Sempre será impresso

    if(numero == 5) // Se numero = 5, vai pro próximo laço
        continue;

    console.log(numero); // Só será impresso quando numero for diferente de 5
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Como funciona o continue?

Simplesmente ignora a iteração atual.

> Em que situações o seu uso é útil?

Depende muito da regra de negócio. 
Pode verificar mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973115/when-to-use-the-continue-keyword-in-c-sharp).

> Porque a saída não imprimi o nome Miriam?

Não imprimi, justamente porque na iteração onde o nome é igual a Miriam, é utilizado o `continue` que salta para a próxima iteração, neste caso, Pedro.