# Pular Registro dentro de um while

Tags: php, while, break

Gostaria de saber como é que eu pulo um registro dentro de um while?

Por exemplo, quando o tipo for 2 ele pula

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
  if($pessoa->tipo == 2){break;}
//continua a exibição de pessoa
}
```

Porém, ao executar isso ele para a execução de todo o while, como resolver?

Comment: Pode fazer algo como `if($pessoa->tipo != 2){ //executa todas ações...}` quando o tipo for 2 nenhum registro será exibido. Se precisar que apenas um registro do tipo 2 seja pulado adicione um flag para controlar isso.

Comment: Dá uma olhada:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207170/para-que-serve-o-controle-de-fluxo-continue

Answer (score 7):

Usar o comando break irá quebrar o loop realmente. Para você continuar normalmente use o continue;

Ou seja..

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
  if($pessoa->tipo == 2)
    continue;
 //  não irá executar os comandos que tiverem após essa condição.
}
```

Comment: `if($pessoa->tipo != 2)`

Comment: Ou isso ... mas cada tem sua opção.

Comment: No caso ele quer pular o 2, então deveria ser diferente, e não igual, se for igual, ele só vai continuar a ação quando o valor for 2

Comment: Então testa primeiro e depois fala o resultado.

Answer (score 5):

Só executa a condição se diferente de 2

```
 while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
    if($pessoa->tipo != 2){
     //continua a exibição de pessoa
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Pode montar uma lógica que 'exclua' os registro do tipo 2, pergutando na comparação o tipo é diferente de dois? Em código fica dessa forma:

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
  if($pessoa->tipo != 2){
    //executa todas as ações ... dos demais tipos
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Todas as respostas já satisfazem a sua necessidade, mas proponho ainda uma abordagem diferente:

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
  if( in_array($pessoa->tipo, array(/* 2,...outros valores que devem ser pulados*/) ) ){
    continue;
  }
}
```

Ou ainda

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
  if( ! in_array($pessoa->tipo, array(/* 2,...outros valores que devem ser pulados*/) ) ){
    /* Seu código */
  }
}
```

Desse modo acredito ficar um pouco mais fácil definir em quais registros (Se for mais de um) ele deve pular.

https://repl.it/IpE9

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer ignorar o `tipo` de `2` completamente, seria ideal não obtê-los do banco de dados, usando por exemplo:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE tipo != 2";
```

*Se o  `2` é tipo máximo, pode usar o `tipo < 2`.*

Dessa forma o `mysqli_fetch_object` irá obter apenas os valores onde o  `tipo` não é `2`, sem necessidade de tratar isto no PHP.

---

Uma outra opção, diferente das demais, é utilizar o `GOTO`, *alá `jmp`*:

```
while($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){

  if($pessoa->tipo === '2'){
     goto fim;
  }

  echo 'Você não é 2!';  // Executa o que tem que fazer.

  fim: // Se ele for `2` ele vem direto para cá. :D
}
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3097f36c8179cb443dacc8742ad2a6294b953cf1)**