# Como percorrer um array pulando alguns indices?

Tags: javascript, array

Existe uma forma nativa de fazer isso?

```
for (var i in vetor) {
    for (var j in vetor) {
        if (i == j) {
            // pula o i
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de pular o `i` dentro dos parenteses do segundo for?

Comment: nao, seria percorrer o array exceto o indice i.

Comment: [Para que serve o controle de fluxo continue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207170/para-que-serve-o-controle-de-fluxo-continue)

Answer (score 10):

Sim, existe. Basta utilizar o [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue). Neste caso, como você deseja interagir com o *loop* mais externo, você deverá especificar um *label* para o mesmo e utilizá-lo junto ao `continue`. O *label* pode ser especificado com um identificador antes do `for`, seguido de dois pontos (`:`).

```js
const vetor = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

loop_i: for (let i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    loop_j: for (let j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
        if (i == j) continue loop_i;
        console.log("i:", i, "j:", j);
    }
}
```

Perceba que no exemplo o valor de `j` só é percorrido até o valor atual de `i`.

Comment: Desconhecia a existência de labels em javascript. Interessante :)

Answer (score 4):

Deve ser algo assim que deseja:

```
for (var i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < vetor.length; j++) {
        if (vetor[i] == vetor[j]) {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/Gaps.js).

Percorrendo o vetor através do índice você tem total controle de como ele vai sendo incrementado já que é uma variável como outra qualquer.

Comment: na verdade eu queria era percorrer todas as posicoes de um array exceto a posicao i, nao percorrer ate i.

Comment: basta  trocar o if para ser `if (vetor[i] == vetor[j])`

Comment: Pensei que existisse algo mais magico.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando as respostas existentes, dependendo do que precisa é só inverter a lógica.

Troque o `i == j` por `i != j` e faça o que precisa dentro do `if`:

```
for (var i in vetor) {
    for (var j in vetor) {
        if (i != j) { 
            // Faz o que tem que fazer aqui, já vai pular o i == j naturalmente
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você leu minha mente. Moderadores do SOpt agora tem superpoderes! :P

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu só conheço os "superpoderes" que vem com o ♦, mas são bem menos do que o pessoal geralmente imagina kkkk.