# Por que esse if checa "se for !false" ao invés de "se for true"?

Tags: javascript, if, estilo-de-codificação, booleano

Me deparei com esse trecho de código:

```js
function showPrimes(n) {

  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if (!isPrime(i)) continue;

    alert(i);  // a prime
  }
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

O que achei peculiar foi a lógica do código estar escrita para verificar `!isPrime(i)`, e não `isPrime(i)`

```js
if (!isPrime(i)) continue;
```

O que me incomoda é que eu não vi motivos pra inverter o valor de `isPrime(i)`, então porque foi invertido? Não é a primeira vez que vejo algo assim, existe algum motivo específico pra isso?

[Onde encontrei o código](https://javascript.info/function-basics).

Comment: Você sabe o que o `continue` faz?

Comment: E porque não deveria? Por que está questionando isso?

Comment: Vale a pena ler a referência sobre a palavra-chave [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue).

Comment: Entendo o continue completamente. A dúvida tem relação com o porquê da lógica do código ter sido escrita dessa forma, uma vez que não é tão inteligível quanto fazer o contrário.

Comment: Eu programo similar à este caso, também tem uma observação importante que é uma boa prática escrever uma função de validação verdadeira no caso `isPrime()` em vez de `notIsPrime()`, e fazer a negação no ato da validação. O uso de `if` seguido de `continue` evita muita identação do código após várias validações.

Comment: `!isPrime(n)` ."Se não for o primeiro", a pessoa fez isso para não precisar criar outro método `isNotPrime(n)`, `isPrime` é um nome da importância do método... ele está sendo usado como uma validação invertida...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Não existe nenhum grande mistério por traz desse código, é apenas uma prática de programação para evitar indentações.

No seu exemplo pode parecer trivial, mas imagine blocos de códigos maiores. Você pode ter 3 `if`s aninhados, resultando em 3 indentações, ou 3 `continue` que não geram nenhuma indentação. Qual dos dois códigos você acha mais elegante?

```
for (valor of array) {

    if (condicao1) {
       // Algum código aqui

       if (condicao2) {
           // Mais código aqui

           if (condicao3) {
              // Restante do código

           }
       }
    }
}
```

---

```
for (valor of array) {
    if (!condicao1) continue;

    // Algum código aqui

    if (!condicao2) continue;

    // Mais código aqui

    if (!condicao3) continue;

    // Restante do código
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Neste caso específico a pessoa fez assim porque quis fazer. Não tem uma motivação clara e que deveria ser assim, então você está coberto de razão. Para os adeptos de boas práticas, isso não é errado, mas não é uma boa prática porque criou um desvio de fluxo mais difícil de acompanhar, ainda que para este exemplo isso não seja tão relevante, passaria ser quando este código começasse crescer. Código indentado costuma ser mais legível que um desvio, por isso as pessoas dizem que deve-se [evitar `goto`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20660/101) (não abolir), e o `continue` é uma forma de `goto`.

Poderia ter um contexto que isso fizesse mais sentido que a forma sem a negação, mas não esse, não é um péssimo exemplo, mas ele é questionável. Este código seria melhor escrito assim:

```js
function showPrimes(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) if (isPrime(i)) console.log(i);
}

function isPrime(n) {
  for (let i = 2; i < n; i++) if (n % i == 0) return false;
  return true;
}

showPrimes(20);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ToBeOrNotToBe.js).

Há uma corrente de pessoas que defende menos controle de fluxo que é o exemplo que eu postei, e há outra que defende menos blocos de execução que é o exemplo da pergunta. Eu defendo que deve fazer o que parece mais óbvio e legível, que mostre mais a intenção do que deseja. Tem uns casos que tentar evitar o `continue` produz códigos bem esquisitos e complicados de entender.

Já falei um pouco mais [sobre o comando em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80589/101) e que eu acho que dá uma ideia melhor do `continue`.