# "if" elegante em PHP

Tags: php, if, estilo-de-codificação

```
(!file_exists($pathFize) ? $response = false : $response = true);

if ($response == true) {
//executa o código ok
}
```

Gostaria de sugestões de como fazer isso de forma mais elegante, lembrando que tudo isso está dentro de uma função maior que precisa retornar um `$response = true` ou `false` de acordo com a resposta da condicional (se o arquivo existe) que nada mais é que uma verificação de segurança.

Por exemplo, no primeiro `$response = false` eu gostaria de encerrar todo o *loop* de repetição e trabalhar em cima do erro `File not exist`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A primeira tentativa de deixar mais elegante:

```
if (file_exists($pathFize)) {
```

Mas se for usar esse dado muitas vezes então é melhor (ou a forma mais correta possível fazendo assim):

```
$response = file_exists($pathFize)

if ($response) {
```

Se quer fazer certo mesmo, e aí não é questão de elegância, não deve verificar se o arquivo existe, a não ser que a lógica seja realmente determinar se o arquivo existe ou não, só isto, então não pode fazer assim. Se a intenção é acessar o arquivo, o acesse e verifique se o acesso deu certo. Se não conseguiu acessar por qualquer razão trate o erro. Se fizer o que está tentando então poderá ter uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) (não é o foco explicar aqui até porque pode estar querendo só verificar a existência mesmo).

Não analisei se a lógica está correta até porque pelo trecho e pelo postado não dá para saber.

Um dos pontos que fica mais elegante é não comparar uma variável que tem valor booleano com um literal booleano, porque o resultado sempre será igual ao da variável, portanto está usando um código redundante, pode usar a variável diretamente. O mesmo vale para uma expressão que gere um valor booleano.

Mas note que isso só funciona se o valor for garantidamente booleano. Se houver a possibilidade do valor ser outro (PHP tem tipagem dinâmica e fraca e pode acontecer isso em algumas situações. Neste caso não tem problema, é booleano garantidamente, pelo menos de acordo com a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Não faz sentido usar um operador de negação na expressão (`!file_exists($pathFize)`) para obter o valor invertido do que quer, por isso quando eu usei eu só eliminei o operador, o seu código está fazendo uma dupla inversão, portanto pegando o valor original.

E reforço que se você pega um valor boobleano (o retorno de `file_exists()` é um booleano de acordo com a documentação) não tem porque verificar o valor se o que deseja é um booleano, você já tem esse valor, use-o de forma direta. Se o seu exemplo quisesse ele invertido, ou seja, se quer `false` quando ele retorna `true` e vice versa aí faria sentido usar o operador `!` para inverter, mas nem é o que quer no exemplo.

Um último ponto é que é bem esquisito usar um operador condicional (que alguns chamam erroneamente de ternário) para executar um comando complexo, em geral você só deveria gerar valores de forma direta. Vamos pensar que gostaria de gerar um número por alguma razão, o mais elegante seria fazer isto:

```
$response = funcaoQueRetornaBool() ? 1 : 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/IfConditional.php).

Percebeu que a atribuição está fora do operador e não dentro como fez?

Funciona porque uma atribuição em PHP é uma [expressão e não um *statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101) puro (um *statement* aceita só declarações então fica confuso) então o operador aceita a atribuição, já que ele espera expressões. Se a atribuição fosse só *statement* não aceitaria.

Já expliquei essa questão do booleano com mais detalhes em alguns lugares:

- [Por que o if funciona apenas com o retorno de um método?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165494/101)
- ["== true" é útil para alguma coisa? É melhor "!" ou "== false"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/315434/101)
- [Atribuir uma expressão a uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101)
- [Porque esse if checa "se for !false" ao invés de "se for true"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408772/101)

Comment: Perfeito amigo!
Gostei deste seu último exemplo, pode ser uma melhor forma de se obter o resultado esperado...

No geral eu verifico apenas se o arquivo existe para saber se eu posso o excluir, não faz sentido eu tentar excluir um arquivo que não exista (até por que isso me retornaria um error)

Vou inclusive tentar aplicar da forma como a qual você descreveu com o "operador condicional" (e não ternário rs)

Volto aqui para dizer o resultado.

Desde já muito grato por sua resposta completa

Comment: Você tem razão... acabei de ler seu post sobre "condições de corrida" entendi melhor sobre e hoje posso editar meu código para evitar tal situação. Obrigado.